# The "code" argument must be of type number error in NestJs/Prisma

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am developing an app using NestJS and Prisma. however, i keep getting this error.
I have been looking for the "code" inside my project but none found. I am still able to run and deploy the project without any issue.
But it keeps giving me this. Really annoying.

Not sure if you have any idea ?
Thank you

```
TypeError: The "code" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('SIGTERM')
at process.set [as exitCode] (node:internal/bootstrap/node:124:9)
at process.exit (node:internal/process/per_thread:188:24)
at process.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:99:2170)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
at process.emit (node:events:511:28)
at process.emit (../node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:516:21)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed in the next Prisma release (possibly 4.14.0), see https://github.com/prisma/prisma/pull/18899.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks for responding.